# is there a way to access index or datable values in a Primevue datatable?

Tags: vue.js, datatables, primevue

I have a datatable in Primevue and I am trying to access my data inside of the datatable html for a v-if that can not be done inside of a slot. In a simple v-for, it can be done like this `v-for="(product, i) in products"` then I would either access my products array with the index of i or I'd use product... Is there any way to do this inside of the `<DataTable :value="products">` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, data can be accessed through a function on a component like so:

```html
<DataTable v-model:expandedRows="expandedRows" :rowClass="showExpander"></Column>
```

In your methods:

```js
showExpander(data) {
    return data.variants && data.variants.length ? '' : 'no-expander';
},
```

In Your Css:

```css
:deep(.no-expander .p-row-toggler) {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There don't seem to be a way to determine an index in PrimeVue `DataTable.`

In `DataTable` you can access the row data through `slotProps`, for example.

```html
    <Column field="name" header="Name">
        <template #body="slotProps">
            <div>
                {{slotProps.data.name}}
            </div>
        </template>
    </Column>
```

Comment: Yeah the problem lies here `<Column :expander="true" headerStyle="width: 3em"></Column>` this is outside of any slot templating and i need to access the data for a v-if directive

Answer (score 0):

The {data} property should give you access to a row value.

Try this:

```
            <Column header="headerName">
                <template #body="{data}">
                    {{ data.arrayProp[index].propName }}
                </template>
            </Column>
```